# Como ejecutar comando de consola (Chrome DevTools) vía js o jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

La estructura de mi web es la siguiente

HTML:

```
<pre id="htmlCode">
// Contenido del sitio
</pre>
```

Abriendo la pagina desde Google chrome e ingresando en las DevTools - Consola
si yo ejecuto este comando:

```
copy($('#htmlCode').html())
```

al hacer  `Ctrl + V`, se pega todo el HTML que esta dentro de ese `<pre>`

Mi pregunta es, como ejecuto ese comando via JQuery o JavaScript?
(Mi intencion es que al hacer click en un boton se ejecute dicho comando y que en mi portapapeles quede el codigo que esta dentro de ese `<pre>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo mediante [`Document#execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand). Hay una lista de comandos que son implementadas de acuerdo al navegador.

**Ejemplo**:

```js
function copy (node) {
  let range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(node);
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);
   
  let support = document.execCommand('copy');
  if (support) {
    console.info('Código copiado al portapeles');
  } else {
    console.error('Tu navegador no soporta execCommand');
  }
}
```

```html
<pre id="htmlCode">
let saludo = 'Hola';
</pre>

<button id="copy" onclick="copy(htmlCode)">Copiar texto</button>
```

**Soporte para el comando** `copy`:

- IE 10+
- Chrome 43+
- Firefox 41+
- Opera 29+

---

**Fallback**

Puedes tener un fallback en caso el navegador no soporte esta API. Hay librerías que te permiten copiar al portapeles como es el caso de [Clipboard.js](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/).

```js
new Clipboard('#copy');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.6.1/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<pre id="htmlCode">
let magicWord = '¿Hay alguno?';
</pre>

<button id="copy" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#htmlCode">Copiar texto</button>
```

Puedes saber si un comando es soportado por el navegador por medio de [`Document.queryCommandSupported`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/queryCommandSupported).

Comment: Gustavo, muchisimas gracias!! 
Pude hacerlo a traves del codigo javascript que me adjuntaste, lo ejecuta a la perfeccion tal y como lo queria, te agradezco tu tiempo y tu ayuda!

No tuve suerte utilizando clipboard.js, por algun motivo el comando no se ejecuta nunca y nunca copia el texto deseado.

Comment: @SantaAQ acabo de probar el código con Clipboard.js y funciona como se espera.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo con Javascript puro el cual puedes adaptar si lo deseas.

El código está comentado. Se usa en este caso el comando copy, invocado desde [Document.execCommand()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

Nota:

Este código no funciona en ciertos navegadores con versiones antiguas.

```js
function copiarAlPortapapeles(elem) {
   // crear elemento de texto oculto si no existe
    var destinoId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
    var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
    var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
    if (isInput) {
        // usar la fuente original del elemento para seleccionar y copiar
        destino = elem;
        origenSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
        origenSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        // usa un formulario temporal para seleccionar y copiar
        destino = document.getElementById(destinoId);
        if (!destino) {
            var destino = document.createElement("textarea");
            destino.style.position = "absolute";
            destino.style.left = "-9999px";
            destino.style.top = "0";
            destino.id = destinoId;
            document.body.appendChild(destino);
        }
        destino.textContent = elem.textContent;
    }
    // selecciona el contenido
    var actualFoco = document.activeElement;
    destino.focus();
    destino.setSelectionRange(0, destino.value.length);
    
    // copia la selección
    var hecho;
    try {
       hecho = document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch(e) {
        hecho = false;
    }
    // restaurar el foco
    if (actualFoco && typeof actualFoco.focus === "function") {
        actualFoco.focus();
    }
    
    if (isInput) {
        // restaurar seleccion previa
        elem.setSelectionRange(origenSelectionStart, origenSelectionEnd);
    } else {
        // limpiar contenido temporal
        destino.textContent = "";
    }
    return hecho;
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<pre id="copiaOrigen">Texto a copiar</pre>

<button id="btnCopiar" onclick="copiarAlPortapapeles(copiaOrigen)">Copiar texto</button><br><br>
<!--    <input type="text" id="copiaOrigen" value="Texto a copiar"> -->
<input type="text" placeholder="Click aquí y presione Ctrl-V para ver el contenido del Portapapeles">
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta! Estuve observando y note lo siguiente. Este codigo que me adjuntas sirve en caso de tener un TextArea o un Input como origen de los datos, en mi caso el origen del dato a copiar esta dentro de un <pre>, y mi idea es copiar su contenido en lenguaje HTML. Como podria adaptarlo para mi necesidad? ya que observando tu código no logro ver una manera de adaptarlo.

Comment: @SantaAQ Lo importante es el Id del elemento, no el tipo de elemento. En el código, para copiar JS se fija en el elemento que tenga el id= copiaDestino:  `copyToClipboard(document.getElementById("copiaDestino"));` he editado la respuesta poniendo un <pre> en vez de un input y como puedes ver, la copia de hace dando clic al Botón copiar, como antes. Luego puedes hacer el Paste en el input de abajo y verás que se verá el texto copiado.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, creí que si el elemento distaba de los detallados no iba a funcionar, pero gracias a tu ejemplo pude ver que no era asi. Gracias por tu tiempo y por tu respuesta! :)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que estás buscando es la función eval().

[eval - JavaScript MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval)

```
eval($('#htmlCode').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instala este plugins y podrás ejecutar código Jquery muy fácil:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquerify/gbmifchmngifmadobkcpijhhldeeelkc